# Shell script output and input from c programs

Tags: shell, shell-scripting

I am new to Shell scripting.How am I supposed to take the output of a c program that i execute  and give it as an input to another c program all using shell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `program1` sends data to stdout and `program2` receives data from stdin:

```
program1 | program2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about bash [pipes](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) and [redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html). In particular to pass the output of one program to the input of another use the `|` operator

```
program | another_program
```

Comment: I am also asked to take input from a text file and feed it as input to a cprogram and execute it. how?

Comment: If you read the links I provided in my answer you will find the answer.